API Gateway - CORS Policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status
I'm trying to make a simple webpage where one can upload a picture, and using API gateway the image is uploaded to a s3 bucket. Here is the front-end code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Upload Photo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Upload Photo to S3</h1>
  <input type="file" id="photo" />
  <button onclick="uploadPhoto()">Upload</button>

  <script>
    async function uploadPhoto() {
      const fileInput = document.getElementById('photo');
      const file = fileInput.files[0];

      if (!file) {
        alert('Please select a file first!');
        return;
      }

      // Generate a unique file name
      //const fileName = `uploads/${Date.now()}_${file.name}`;
      const fileName = `${Date.now()}_${file.name}`;

        try {
          // Construct the dynamic URL with the object (fileName)
          const apiUrl = `https://example.com/API/upload_data/${fileName}`;

          const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: new Headers(),
            body: file  // Send the raw file directly
            });

          const result = await response.json();
          if (response.ok) {
            alert('Upload successful!');
          } else {
            alert('Upload failed: ' + result.message);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error uploading photo:', error);
        }
      };
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Using postman and the API url, I can succesfully upload the image.
I am using cloudfront to serve my webpage. When I try to upload the image from my website, I get the following CORS error:
Access to fetch at 'https://example.execute-api.us-east-example.com/API/upload_data/1729610767592_image.jpeg' from origin 'https://--.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I tried a few different things to overcome this error, but nothing seems to solve it. I added options methods and even a proxy+ integration, but the CORS error is persistent.
For the proxy+ integration:
    export const handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://--.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
    };


Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you very much in advance!
I have tried to add different routes to handle the CORS preflight requests.
